# Undeclared identifier error for modifier

Tags: solidity, modifiers

I am new to solidity and am confused on why I am getting this undeclared identifier error:

I have this modifier:

```
modifier isRegistered(uint ID_num){
    require (Array[ID_num].exists, "Object DNE");
    _;
}
```

Then I call it in this function but I am getting the undeclared identifier error.

```
function newAdoption(address addy1, address addy2) public isRegistered(ID_number){

}
```

Where am I going wrong here?

Answer (score 1):

Your 'ID_number' in the modifier in the newAdoption function doesn't exists.

You shouldn't rely on an user input since any user can pass any value and it's therefore not trust worthy.

I don't know what you are trying to do, but you should try a pattern like this:

```
  struct MyUser {
    bool exists;
    address userAddress;
  }

  mapping (address => MyUser) public myUsers;

  modifier isRegistered(address userAddress){
    require (myUsers[userAddress].exists, "Object DNE");
    _;
  }

  function newAdoption(address addy1, address addy2) public isRegistered(msg.sender){

}
```

That way, your smart contract checks if the address contacting it is a user.

Edit: To make it more simple, you could also do that:

```
  mapping (address => bool) public myUsers;

  modifier isRegistered(address userAddress){
    require (myUsers[userAddress], "Object DNE");
    _;
  }

  function addUser(address _newUser) external onlyOwner() {
       myUsers[_newUser] = true;
}

  function newAdoption(address addy1, address addy2) public isRegistered(msg.sender){

}
```

Comment: So everytime a new user is created will the mapping automatically kick in and add that user into the hash map? @OlivierD

Comment: Well you will have to create a addUser(address _newUser) function that is owner protected. Check my edited answer. Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

The reason why it's showing that error is because `ID_number` doesn't exist in the function scope. Surely you don't have any state variable in this contract with the name `ID_number` and function arguments do not have that name either.
therefore `ID_number` must be a argument of that function (since arguments are already been included in the function scope when you use modifiers) or any other variable that belongs to that scope.

```
function newAdoption(address addy1, address addy2) public isRegistered(addy2){

}
```

---

```
function newAdoption(address addy1, address addy2) public isRegistered(any_variable_that_lies_in_this_scope){

}
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

function newAdoption(address addy1, address addy2) public isRegistered(ID_number)

in method signature you're pass ID_number in modifier but you're not passing ID_number param in newAdoption

you can just pass address addy1 or address addy2 in modifier